# Query Clarification on multiple table insert

Tags: t-sql, format

I have a table populated by CSV raw data

```
| NNAME  | DateDriven | username |
|--------------------------------|
| Thunder| 1-1-1999   | mickey   | 
|--------------------------------|
```

And an existing MSSQL database

```
> Tables 
Drivers       
| ------------- | 
| ID | username |
|---------------| 
|  1 | mickey   |        
|  2 | jonny    |
|  3 | ryan     |
-----------------

Cars
-----------------------------
| ID | NNAME   | DateDriven |
|---------------------------|
|    |         |            |
-----------------------------

Car_Drivers Table
-----------------------
| Cars_ID | Driver_ID |
|---------------------|
|         |           |
-----------------------
```

How can I take the cvs table data and insert it into the above? I am very lost!

- CARS IDs are identity(1,1). Table Car_Drivers has a composite primary key off two foreign keys.

What I think I need to do is create a join to convert username to ID but I am getting lost completing the insert query.

Desired outcome

```
Cars Table
-----------------------------
| ID | NNAME   | DateDriven |
|---------------------------|
| 1  | Thunder | 1-1-1999   |
-----------------------------

Car_Drivers Table
-----------------------
| Cars_ID | Driver_ID |
|---------------------|
|    1    |     1     |
-----------------------
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Are you authorized to declassify the DDL for the tables? That saves us from guessing whether `DateDriven` is `NVarChar(MAX)` or `Date`. There isn't anything in your sample data that looks like comma separated values (CSV). Is that because you've already figured out how to split the data into rows in the first (unnamed) table or because the sample data isn't representative of the problem at hand?

Comment: I updated the post. The CSV data has already been processed into SQL and all the field types match.

Answer (score 0):

The following ought to do what you need. The problem is that you need to keep some temporary data around as rows are inserted into `Cars`, but some of the data is from a different table.  `Merge` provides the answer:

```
-- Create the test data.
declare @CSVData as Table ( NName NVarChar(16), DateDriven Char(8), Username NVarChar(16));
insert into @CSVData ( NName, DateDriven, Username ) values
  ( N'Thunder', '1-1-1999', N'mickey' );
select * from @CSVData;

declare @Drivers as Table ( Id SmallInt Identity, Username NVarChar(16) );
insert into @Drivers ( Username ) values
  ( N'mickey' ), ( N'jonny' ), ( N'ryan' );
select * from @Drivers;

declare @Cars as Table ( Id SmallInt Identity, NName NVarChar(16), DateDriven Char(8) );

declare @CarDrivers as Table ( Cars_Id SmallInt, Driver_Id SmallInt );

-- Temporary data needed for the   @CarDrivers   table.
declare @NewCars as Table ( Username NVarChar(16), Cars_Id SmallInt );

-- Merge the new data into   @Cars .
--   MERGE   allows the use of   OUTPUT  with references to columns not inserted,
--   e.g.   Username .
merge into @Cars
  using ( select NName, DateDriven, Username from @CSVData ) as CSVData
  on 1 = 0
    when not matched by target then
      insert ( NName, DateDriven ) values ( CSVData.NName, CSVData.DateDriven )
  output CSVData.Username, Inserted.Id into @NewCars;

-- Display the results.
select * from @Cars;

-- Display the temporary data.
select * from @NewCars;

-- Add the connections.
insert into @CarDrivers ( Cars_Id, Driver_Id )
  select NewCars.Cars_Id, Drivers.Id
    from @NewCars as NewCars inner join
      @Drivers as Drivers on Drivers.Username = NewCars.Username;

-- Display the results.
select * from @CarDrivers;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f0331380ba69c943f10115e03f03196c).

Comment: HABO, considering your reply (Thank you!), are the current tables good SQL? Is there a better way either to simplify the storage of data or the process updating the tables? Maybe un-normalize the table one step?

Comment: @CyberChile Do the same cars keep turning up being driven by the same or different users? If so, you might want to move `DateDriven` to `Car_Drivers` to fully normalize the tables. Other than that your tables look okay. Denormalization is generally used for performance reasons lacking better solutions, e.g. indexes and other techniques are inadequate to meet performance requirements.